# How do I declare std::pair as a friend so it sees private default ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, private, friend, std-pair

I am using boost (de)serialization to reconstruct classes without public default ctors, by design.  I declare a private default ctor and declare the boost access class as a friend, and it uses the default ctor as part of its deserialization process.  But it can't reconstruct a `std::pair` unless I make the default ctor public.  I'd rather declare friendship, but I can't figure out how.

Below is a simplified example:

```
class PrivateDC
{
private:
    friend class PrivateDCFriend;
    friend struct std::pair<int, PrivateDC>;
    PrivateDC() = default;
};
class PrivateDCFriend
{
    void f() const
    {
        PrivateDC a;                  // this works, proves friendship
        std::pair<int, PrivateDC> b;  // gets compile error
    }
};
```

The error is "no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::pair<int, PrivateDC>'".  I don't get the error if the default ctor is public.
How can I declare `std::pair` as a friend so this will work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't,

Default construction of `std::pair<T, U>` requires that both `T` and `U` be [DefaultConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible) and `PrivateDC` is not, failing at that requirement causes the default constructor of `std::pair` being excluded from the overload set.

Comment: Thanks Jans.  It's not what I wanted to hear, but I won't waste any more time on it.